# how to write a c++ template that gives the maximum of two args?

Tags: c++, templates, max

Both arguments are guaranteed to be integers.

How do I write myMax such that:

```
myMax<1, 2>; // 2
myMax<3, 2>; // 3  ?
```

I want this to be evaluated at compile time, not run time. (Need to then use this with sizeof for a typelist to allocate space for a variant.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template <int x, int y>
struct myMax
{
    static const int value = (x > y) ? x : y;
};
```

If you are going to be using it only with sizes, you can use `std::size_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: @gf:  I know; that was a copy and paste failure.  It's been fixed.

Comment: I thought you knew, just thought you overlooked.